# Would the following proof that a continuous function $f$ from a compact space $X\rightarrow Y$ is uniformly continuous fail?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification, compactness

Both in the lectures as in the book (Baby Rudin) the proof is more complicated, which makes me wonder if the following, simpler proof that I had in mind wouldn't work. If so, could someone explain why it fails?

---

**Theorem**: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function from a compact metric space $X$ to $Y$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Chose $\epsilon >0$, by continuity for every $x\in X$ there exists $\delta _x>0$ such that $$d(x,x_0)<\delta _x\Rightarrow d(f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon$$ for any $x_0\in X$.
Now the collection of open balls $N_{\delta _x}(x)$ forms an open cover of $X$, and thus (by compactness) must have a finite subcover $\{ N_{\delta_{x_1}}(x_1),\ldots ,N_{\delta_{x_n}}(x_n)\}$.

Let $\delta = \min(\delta_{x_1},\ldots ,\delta_{x_n})$. Pick $x\in X$, then for any $x_0\in X$ we have $$d(x,x_0)<\delta \Rightarrow d(x,x_0)<\delta_x\Rightarrow d(f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon .$$

Comment: It's not clear that $d(x, x_0) < \delta$ implies $d(x,x_0)<\delta_{x}$. In principle we could have $\inf_{x} \delta_{x}=0$, for instance, in which case the implication is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\delta$ is not necessarily smaller than or equal to $\delta_x$, since $x$ may well be a point other than $x_1, ..., x_n$. However, it is true that $x$ is covered by some $N_{\delta_{x_i}}(x_i)$, and you should refer to this $x_i$ (with adequate modification to the radii of neighborhoods) in order to make the argument work. More specifically, you'd probably take the finite subcover of $\{N_{\delta_{x}/2}(x)\}$, where those $\delta_x$ are for $\epsilon/2$.